# Manipulate the main page using popup.js Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension to turn a page red

This is my manifest file:

```
 {
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "icons":{"128":"icon_128.png"},
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And here is my `background.js` file:

```
function mainFunction(){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Here is my popup.js file:

```
document.getElementById("btnDownloadListings").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
        backgroundPage.mainFunction();
    });
}, false);
```

When I click the button the popup.html or the popup tab turns red but the main page does not.

Comment: pageAction.onClicked won't work when default_popup is defined. Replace `page_action` with `browser_action` and remove `background` section completely and instead send a message from the popup script.

Comment: I suggest starting with a working [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) and extend it with your functionality.

Comment: I followed you advice and downloaded a simple extension name make_page_red which makes page read on extension icon click. Problem is that I also want a popup.html to appear so I added `popup.html` and added a button in there. But when I click the button only the popup turns red. So after more research I found that we can run scripts on the background page from the popup.js using the `chrome.runtime.getBackground` api which you can see in my above question that I edited. But it is still not working as only the popup is turning red

Comment: That demo won't help you as you don't need the background script at all. Use the demo named "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color" instead.